# For some reason my form in Visual Basic will not show

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I was playing around trying to learn about using timers in Visual Basic (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional) as I am only starting out. I wrote a short piece of code to open a form (containing a label that read "Welcome" in black text, so I wouldn't show up), which would start a timer that would trigger different sentences to come up. Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private TimerTicks As Integer = Nothing
Private userName As String = "Phillip"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackColor = Color.Black
    Timer.Interval = 1000
    Timer.Enabled = True
    TextLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black
    TextLabel.BackColor = Color.Black
    EventsLine()
End Sub

Private Sub EventsLine()

    Do Until TimerTicks = 20
        If TimerTicks = 1 Then
            TextLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
        ElseIf TimerTicks = 3 Then
            TextLabel.Text = "Your name is " & userName & ", right?"
        ElseIf TimerTicks = 10 Then
            TextLabel.Text = "Nice to meet you"
        End If
    Loop

    Me.Hide()

End Sub


Private Sub Timer_Tick() Handles Timer.Tick
    TimerTicks = TimerTicks + 1
End Sub
End Class
```

There is obviously something horrifically wrong with my code as when I run the program, the form doesn't even show up. I don't know if it's loading or just hiding as I tried using 'Me.Show()' in the 'Form1_Load' Sub and it showed, but It just didn't respond or show anything.

This is all for learning purposes, so please feel free to rip my code apart and tell me every mistake I've made, but please be nice about it :)

Comment: Why did you tag this with VBA?

Comment: put the `EventsLine` code in the Timer Tick, maybe use a slightly longer interval, and maybe use `TextLabel.Refresh` to force the new text to show up after you cahnge it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 'Private Sub EventsLine() in the timer but don't use the do until, then it works.
If you use If TimerTicks < 20 Then , you get the same.

```
Private TimerTicks As Integer = Nothing
Private userName As String = "Phillip"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackColor = Color.Black
    Timer.Interval = 1000
    Timer.Enabled = True
    TextLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black
    TextLabel.BackColor = Color.Black

End Sub


'Private Sub EventsLine()

'    Do Until TimerTicks = 20
'        If TimerTicks = 1 Then
'            TextLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
'        ElseIf TimerTicks = 3 Then
'            TextLabel.Text = "Your name is " & userName & ", right?"
'        ElseIf TimerTicks = 10 Then
'            TextLabel.Text = "Nice to meet you"
'        End If
'    Loop

'    Me.Hide()

'End Sub


Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    TimerTicks = TimerTicks + 1
    If TimerTicks < 20 Then
        If TimerTicks = 1 Then
            TextLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
        ElseIf TimerTicks = 3 Then
            TextLabel.Text = "Your name is " & userName & ", right?"
        ElseIf TimerTicks = 10 Then
            TextLabel.Text = "Nice to meet you"
        End If

    Else

    End If


    If TimerTicks = 20 Then
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're using a timer that is running on the same thread as the UI thread, and the UI thread is being blocked by the `EventsLine` method (which is called from the `Load` event).  Since the event message loop never reaches the `Tick` handler, there's never an opportunity to increment timer ticks.

I would suggest reading up on the differences between timers in .NET.  Some of them are better for multi-threaded operations.  This is a good resource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Also, you might also want to learn something about the way that event-driven applications function.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop